# How to select data from data frame in R when there are multiple entries for a user?

Tags: r

I have some JSON data obtained from my analytics for a mobile application. The data measures how they use the app, what activities they prefer etc.

I am trying to build 'profiles' for my users, and say how their behaviour changes on day 0 vs day 7.

For each user, my analytics spit out an ID so I can identify them. These are shown in 'userID' column.

Is there a way I can pull out the data for users that have multiple entries. Users that only open app once are no good for my profile analysis.

For example, I would only want data for user 1234374648

| userID | Button pressed | points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234374648 | Vaccine | 5 |
| 123437464 | Vaccine | 4 |
| 784628178 | Medicine | 2 |
| 652847484 | Vaccine | 2 |

Comment: When asking a question about finding a specific "thing" in your data, it is typically good if that "thing" is *actually present*. For instance, you're looking for repeated instances of any particular `userID`, yet you have four unique values. Please spend a few moments when asking questions to give relevant data.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Carla Louise! Your question is framed well for a first question, three requests for future questions: (1) relevant sample data, see my previous comment; (2) please show code you've attempted, otherwise it might appear as if you are treating StackOverflow as a free-code service; (3) the tag recommendation system is imperfect, please pay attention. In this case, while you may get your data from JSON, that has no bearing on the data or problem here. Also, the [tag:rstudio] tag specifically mentions it is for the IDE itself, not for general R programming.

Answer (score 0):

I'll augment your sample data, since none of it passes your constraints:

```r
dat <- structure(list(userID = c(1234374648, 123437464, 784628178, 652847484, 1234374648, 123437464, 784628178), Button.pressed = c("Vaccine ", "Vaccine ", "Medicine ", "Vaccine ", "Vaccine ", "Vaccine ", "Medicine "), points = c(5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

dat
#       userID Button.pressed points
# 1 1234374648       Vaccine       5
# 2  123437464       Vaccine       4
# 3  784628178      Medicine       2
# 4  652847484       Vaccine       2
# 5 1234374648       Vaccine       5
# 6  123437464       Vaccine       4
# 7  784628178      Medicine       2
```

(All `userID` are duplicated except the 4th, `652847484`, so I would expect 6 rows in the outputs below.)

### Base R

```r
morethan1 <- ave(dat$userID, dat$userID, FUN = length) > 1
morethan1
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
dat[morethan1,]
#       userID Button.pressed points
# 1 1234374648       Vaccine       5
# 2  123437464       Vaccine       4
# 3  784628178      Medicine       2
# 5 1234374648       Vaccine       5
# 6  123437464       Vaccine       4
# 7  784628178      Medicine       2
```

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(userID) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#       userID Button.pressed points
#        <dbl> <chr>           <int>
# 1 1234374648 "Vaccine "          5
# 2  123437464 "Vaccine "          4
# 3  784628178 "Medicine "         2
# 4 1234374648 "Vaccine "          5
# 5  123437464 "Vaccine "          4
# 6  784628178 "Medicine "         2
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[, .SD[.N > 1,], by = .(userID)][]
#        userID Button.pressed points
#         <num>         <char>  <int>
# 1: 1234374648       Vaccine       5
# 2: 1234374648       Vaccine       5
# 3:  123437464       Vaccine       4
# 4:  123437464       Vaccine       4
# 5:  784628178      Medicine       2
# 6:  784628178      Medicine       2
```